# My front wheel has some play which drives me crazy

Tags: wheels, front

I have a mountain bike and it's front wheel has some play in it. I have replaced the bearings and the whole axle but it was in vain. If you even tighten the cone nuts more than you should do the play is still there. What is happening and does this mean I need a new wheel? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the play is in the wheel axle and not in the head tube bearings? How do you check for the play in the wheel? What kind of brakes do you have? I know that V-brakes and cantilevers when engaged on standing bicycle give similar feeling to head tube play while in fact the play is on the brake bosses.

Comment: You need to track down exactly where the play is. With the wheel out of the bike, can you feel play between the axle and hub?

Comment: And if you have front shocks, that's probably a larger source of "play" than all other factors put together.

Comment: It is surely the wheel that has play. In order to test that I changed my front wheel with one that is pretty new and the play has gone . Also the bike felt more stable as I were shaking it back and forth engaging the front brake. This case seems very strange to me as I don't know what is going one. Has This happened to anyone else ? By the way the wheel is 4 years old and I think I got over  700 km on it. However as I said before I changed the whole axle and bearings and the cups inside are very smooth!! Please help me with this !

Comment: Daniel R Hicks. I have recently changed my fork with a rigid one since I use my bike mostly to commute XD

Comment: On which axis you have play? Let's say X is in the direction of the wheels, Y is the projection of the axle and Z is upwards.

Comment: Do you have enough balls? Are they appropriately sized?

Comment: Well the play is the x axis and I have the appropriate ball bearings. Thank you for your support !!

Comment: the x-axis (front to back) would be the steering head bearings being loose, I would think. Side to side - along the axle is the wheel bearings

Comment: Stupid thought - is there a locknut on the outside of each of the cone nuts?

Comment: 700km is nothing for a wheel bearing. They can easily handle 10000km or more before wear starts to deteriorate their performance. If I were you, I'd try to look very closely *where the movement happens*. Does the wheel move relative to the hub? Does the hub move relative to the fork? Does the fork move relative to the frame? A movement that's large enough to be felt while riding should be visible. Once you know exactly where the movement is, you'll know what to replace/adjust.

Answer (score 1):

If the play is in the wheel, a thought is that the bearing cup in the hub body is loose.  How that would be, I am not sure.  If you can tighten the cones to "too tight", that rules out a broken axle.  Grab the axle and see if you can get it to move.